# What should we do if we need to pass gas while praying?

Tags: tefilla

What should we do if we need to pass gas while praying?

Comment: [MT Tefilah 4:12](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/920166/jewish/Tefilah-and-Birkat-Kohanim-Chapter-Four.htm#v12): "One who desires to pass gas from below and is bothered exceedingly, to the extent that he cannot restrain himself, should walk back four cubits, [expel the gas], and then wait until the gas subsides. He should say... He then returns to his place and prays."

Comment: @Tamir and ShA OC 103